# Расчёт доставки, первые километры бесплатно

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator

сделать первые 300 километров бесплатно, и только после идёт расчёт.

Answer (score 1):

В примере в самом низу кода есть функция

```
function calculate(routeLength) {
    return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
}
```

Вы можете видоизменить её так чтобы она возвращала необходимые вам данные.